# Pattern to find all the data between two words

Tags: regex

I am using the below pattern to find all the data between two words, placed in multiple lines.

/START(.+?)END/

But this doesn't seems to work as expected. Can someone help me out with a exact pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: which tool/language are you using?

Comment: how you define word is it [0-9a-zA-Z]+? and do you need microsoft style regex?

Comment: Please don't use the phrase "didn't work." Instead, give us sample input and the behavior you expected.

Comment: sure, will do that from now if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you can use Python for example.

```
>>> s="""
... START
...   blah1 blah2
...   more blah  
...   and even more blah
... END blah3 blah4 blah5 START blah 6
... text here here                    
... blah7 END ......                  
... START end END                     
... """                            
>>> for item in s.split("END"):
...     if "START" in item:
...        print item [ item.find("START")+len("START") : ]
...

  blah1 blah2
  more blah
  and even more blah

 blah 6
text here here
blah7
 end
```

Split your string on "END", go through each splitted items, check for START,and do a substring. Use the split method of your preferred language.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `s` flag : with this flag, dot (`.`) will match new line characters too.

```
 /start(.+?)end/s
```

Comment: No. The multi-line option will only let the start and end of the line be matched by ^ and $ respectively.

Comment: I thought I edited before anyone saw that - man you are fast. Anyway, `s` is the correct one, right?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to match things like

```
START
  blah blah blah
  more blah
  and even more blah
END
```

? Since `.` does *not* match newlines by default, your regex won't work. You need to supply the single-line (also known as "dot-all") `/s` flag to make it match the newlines.

```
/START(.+?)END/s
```

Comment: Note that the s-flag is more widely known as the DOT-ALL flag, AFAIK. Besides that: +1